# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3291105000"

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

Why is this happening? The string I'm parsing looks clearly like an int. The program is reading from a file, and I know that it's working for the most because this number is way down the list. Any ideas? Also, the program is parsing ints larger than 2.2 billion, so I don't know if it's a size issue.

Comment: Sounds like you know exactly what the problem is already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A signed 32-bit `int` can only be as large as 2^31, or 0x7FFFFFFF (2,147,483,647).  You'll need to use a bigger datatype. `long` will get you up to 2^63. Or the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class will get you an arbitrary sized integer.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such thing as as an `unsigned int` in Java :(

Answer (score 2):

`int` can have a minimum value of `-2,147,483,648` and a maximum value of `2,147,483,647` (inclusive), Your number(from string) falls out of the range

Use `long` instead `Long.parseLong(3291105000)` would work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use a `long`, which can hold 64 bits integers.

- `int`s can only hold integers up to ~2 billion
- `long`s can hold integers up to ~9e18

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, the number is clearly out of range of int and hence you are getting the exception.

4 bytes, signed (two's complement). -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Like all numeric types ints may be cast into other numeric types (byte, short, long, float, double). When lossy casts are done (e.g. int to byte) the conversion is done modulo the length of the smaller type.